# Better alternative for Cursor using While loop to iterate Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Good Day,
I am trying to fetch dates from one of my table, containing records in millions, in database and save them in a variable using Cursor. After fetching dates i am inserting records in db at that particular date. For this I am using While Loop. It turns out that While loop is really slowing down the performance, it is taking about hours to complete execution. I am including a part of a query for further clearance.

```
declare @tranDateCursor cursor; 
declare @today as date; 
begin  

    set @tranDateCursor = cursor
    for
        select distinct transferDate
        from transactions
        where [type] = 'customer'

    open @tranDateCursor
    fetch next from @tranDateCursor
    into @today

    while @@fetch_status = 0  

    begin  

        declare @yesterday as date
        set @yesterday = (
               select top(1) transferDate
               from (
                      select distinct(transferDate) AS transferDate
                      from transactions
                      where transferDate < @today
                        and [type] = 'customer'
                    ) as ODC_DATES
               order by ODC_DATES.transferDate desc
        )  

        insert into transactions([type],transferDate) 
        select 'customer'
                ,@today
        from transactions xt
            right outer join x_itransaction as y
                on y.customer_account = xt.customer_account
                    AND y.transferDate = @yesterday
                    AND xt.transferDate = @today
        where xt.transactionId is null
            and y.transferDate = @yesterday
            and y.[type] ='customer'

    end
end
```

I have tried using Table Variables instead of CURSOR with WHILE loop, but it turns out that it was too taking very much time to run. My concern is that, Is there a better alternative for a while loop in this particular scenario?

Comment: I think, that with all those `###` out there, it's a bit hard to figure it out.

Comment: Haha oh dear... Please add back the names of the essential columns...  Oh and also your entire query.  You have two `begin` statements and no `end`s at all

Comment: Ok, i have added necessary columns. :)
@iamdave yeah it was not included in hurry, as there are two more queries to run in a loop similar to this one. I have included them in edit.

Comment: Could you simply post the structure of the relevant columns for the `transactions` and `x_itransaction` table along with some dummy data and a desired output?  The logic you are using in this query is difficult to follow.

Comment: Often if you want to improve performance of a loop you can rewrite it to multiple sql statements not containing a loop or cursor